# How to display video in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, src

I am using angularJS, I am trying to display the videos in my list and for that I wrote the following lines but I am unable to get the link:

```
<div ng-repeat ='video in vm.videos'>
   <video width="400" controls>
    <source ng-src="videos/{{video.video}}" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support this video.
   </video>
 <source src="videos/{{video.video}}" type="video/mp4">
</div>
```

When I give the name as static it shows my video, can anyone suggest help please?

```
"videos": [
    {
      "_id": "587f5d31ceb2891e31422481",
      "title": "DSDAXAXASXASSX",
      "text": "<p>ASXASXASXASXASX</p>",
      "correlated_duione": "D008133",
      "correlated_duitwo": "ASXASXS",
      "video": "loading.-1484741937856.png,",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ],
```

Comment: What contains `vm.videos` ?

Comment: you problem is adress of videos/...

Comment: go for a snippet and tidy ur html

Comment: `loading.-1484741937856.png,` does not seem like the name file for a video.  Are you sure the `src` attribute is correct?  if you use `src="videos/loading.-1484741937856.png,"` does it work?

Comment: if i give it as a stactic src="videos/loading.-1484741937856.png it works but like this src="videos/{{video.video}}" not wrkng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a small syntax error:

```
<div ng-repeat ='video in vm.videos>
```

You're missing the end quote. Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat ="video in vm.videos">
```

Other that that, it looks correct. If it doesn't work, open the developer console in your browser and see if any HTTP errors were logged. In all likelihood, the link you provided as `videos/{{video.video}}` is broken.

Comment: sorry,its a typo mistake,actually my problem is i am not able to see videos  displyed

Comment: @nlr_p what's the structure of vm.videos? can you post that to your question? (as an edit)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//In your MODULE add a filter (change "myModule" with the proper name )
myModule.filter('videoUrl', function($sce) {
    return function(video) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(video.video);
    };
});
```

```html
<!--In your view-->
<div ng-repeat ='video in vm.videos'>
    <video width="400" ng-src="{{ video | videoUrl }}" controls></video>
</div>
```